# Switch Statement and Case

Tags: java, for-loop, int, switch-statement

I am making code for my CPSC class and I have to print up to a case number that is set for the int.  When I enter "2", the code prints "two potato" eight times instead of "One potato, two potato".

Here is my code I have:

```
public class Potato {

public Potato() {
}

public void count(int c) {     


    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {   
        switch (c % 8) {
            case 1:  System.out.println("One potato"); break;
            case 2:  System.out.println("two potato"); break;
            case 3:  System.out.println("three potato"); break;
            case 4:  System.out.println("four..."); break;
            case 5:  System.out.println("five potato"); break;
            case 6:  System.out.println("six potato"); break;
            case 7:  System.out.println("seven potato"); break;
            case 8:  System.out.println("more!"); break;
            default: break; 
        }
    }


}
}
```

I think my problem is my for-loop, not too sure though, since I am here asking for help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you need 'for' loop?

Comment: What is the point of the `for` loop?  You never use the loop variable `i`.

Comment: Professor said to place the switch statement inside a loop that correctly counts the int counter. I thought for loop would work, by all means, let me know if there is a better solution.

Comment: You have `i` in your loop but `c` in your switch. And why the `% 8`?

Comment: I was going off an example given to me by the professor that contained the % 8

Comment: So I assume it's supposed to print each case from 1, up to the number you entered? And btw, using `%8` will never give `case 8` since that was the devisor. That should be `case 0` instead

Comment: Correct, instead I am receiving the case number I enter eight times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. As others have said, you should use `i%8`. However, for this to work you should also start with `i=1` since `0%8 = 0`. And your `case 8` should be changed to `case 0`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
    switch (i % 8) {
        case 1: System.out.println("One potato"); break;
        case 2: System.out.println("two potato"); break;
        case 3: System.out.println("three potato"); break;
        case 4: System.out.println("four..."); break;
        case 5: System.out.println("five potato"); break;
        case 6: System.out.println("six potato"); break;
        case 7: System.out.println("seven potato"); break;
        case 0: System.out.println("more!"); break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `c % 8 (2 % 8 = 2)`, so in every loop it will execute `case 2` and prints `two potato`. You could use `i % 8` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code is... peculiar:

The main problem is that you are not using the `i` variable that is incremented at the `for` loop. Instead, you are using `c` variable:

```
switch (c % 8)
```

Should be:

```
switch (i % 8)
```

You don't need the `case 8` since there is no way that `i % 8` result in 8. And, looks like you don't need `c` variable at all.